# Dwarf refuses to stay in hospital until she has recuperated

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Two dwarfs were seriously injured. They were treated by a doctor in the hospital, but for some reason both of them suddenly left and started working again. The body part list shows both "lower body" and "right upper leg" in red, and the description states that her lower body is cut open, her kidney is broken etc.

Why did she leave the hospital? Will she recover while working or should I try to force her back in bed again?

Comment: What does the treatment page show for these dwarves?

Comment: The treatment page did not show anything, so it looks like the treatment they actually got was sufficient. But the description "lower body is cut open" does not exactly imply that she is healed an fit for full time working ...

Answer (score 4):

Some time (gaming time) has gone, and it looks like they are healing just fine. The lower body is no longer "cut open" but merly "dented", and the body part is now listed in yellow and not red any more.

I guess we should not worry about body parts listed in red as long as the treatment page does not require any treatment.

She even had a "satisfying sparring session lately". Truly a "short, sturdy creature" :-)

Comment: And all the alcohol can't hurt ;)

Comment: I think if she got sewed up, her status page still sometimes lists her as "cut open", but she's really fine. If she's healing properly, I wouldn't worry about it. The treatment page should show any past treatment performed, such as sutures. Alternately, she might just have gotten impatient waiting for your chief medical dwarf to see to her and checked herself out. If she's "quick to heal" or better, she'll pretty much always heal muscle damage anyway.